# Windows 10- associate Chrome window with an arbitrary virtual desktop on startup

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10, virtual-machine

(W10 tag used b/c only W10 supports multiple virtual desktops. If I read the tag description yet, I should be using VM tag, even though virtual desktops aren't VMs, are they?)

I have 8 virtual desktops. I have 2 or 3 Chrome windows per virtual desktop.

On system boot, Chrome loads all of the windows in whichever virtual desktop I user first. This is inconvenient because I have to manually transport each window to its corresponding virtual desktop. As the number of applications increases, this only becomes more annoying.

Is there a program I can write to do this? With some Google searches, I have seen how to launch programs on startup. However, I also want to associate these instances of Chrome with a virtual desktop.

On startup Windows automatically creates 8 virtual desktops (good!) so I haven't included this in my pseudocode.

Some pseudocode:

```
while (true)
sleep 5 seconds //do this every 5 seconds

 for (each virtual desktop)
{
check what instance of Chrome is running in that window
}

if(startup==1)
{
check the log file on which virtual desktop to dump each instance of Chrome into
put it there
}
```